# NAudio hanging and crashing when default device is changed

Tags: c#, naudio

I've been stuck on this all day, so I'm going to post everything I've been able to find today that might be useful to helping me, it will be a long post. I'm having 2 issues that I believe are related to the same problem. First, let me explain what I am doing. I have 3 Winforms combo boxes that are bound to lists of all of the devices found by MMDeviceEnumerator. Two output device boxes, one input device. I am using the MMDeviceEnumerator to register a callback for whenever the devices are changed, removed, or a default device is set. The callback fires an event that then invokes a delegate to the form thread to re-enumerate the devices into combo boxes. It looks like this:

```
public void OnDefaultDeviceChanged(DataFlow dataFlow, Role deviceRole, string defaultDeviceId)
{
    Devices.OnDevicesUpdated();
}

//The handler called by this event:

private void UpdateDeviceSelectors(object? sender = null, EventArgs? e = null)
{

    Invoke(delegate ()
    {

        int primaryIndex = Devices.PrimaryOutput + 1, secondaryIndex = Devices.SecondaryOutput + 2, microphoneIndex = Devices.Microphone + 1;
        Devices.Refresh();

        try
        {
            SecondaryOutputComboBox.SelectedIndex = secondaryIndex;
            PrimaryOutputComboBox.SelectedIndex = primaryIndex;
            MicrophoneSelectComboBox.SelectedIndex = microphoneIndex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Now for the two issues I have. The first one involves a semi-random crash that leads back to NAudio.Wasapi.dll, where a System.ExecutionEngineException is thrown. It is kind of easy to reproduce. All I do is change the values of the combo boxes, switch the default devices around, and it will randomly crash.

The second issue occurs when another part of my code is involved. I have a microphone injector, which redirects a WaveInEvent that records a selected input device to a WaveOutEvent, like a loopback. Here is the relevant code for this:

```
public void Start()
{

    if (Soundboard.Devices.SecondaryOutput == -2) return;

    micStream = new WaveInEvent();



    micStream.BufferMilliseconds = 50;
    micStream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(Soundboard.Devices.Microphone).Channels);

    micStream.DeviceNumber = Soundboard.Devices.Microphone;

    WaveInProvider waveIn = new(micStream);


    var volumeSampleProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(waveIn.ToSampleProvider());
    volumeSampleProvider.Volume = 1 + Settings.Default.MicrophoneGain;

    virtualCable = new WaveOutEvent();
    virtualCable.DesiredLatency = 150;
    virtualCable.DeviceNumber = Soundboard.Devices.SecondaryOutput;
    virtualCable.Init(volumeSampleProvider);

    micStream.StartRecording();
    virtualCable.Play();

}

public void Stop()
{
    try
    {
        if (micStream != null && virtualCable != null)
        {


            micStream.Dispose();
            micStream = null;

            virtualCable.Dispose();
            virtualCable = null;

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        micStream = null;

        virtualCable = null;
    }
}
```

In the delegate mentioned earlier, I am calling the Stop method of the Mic Injector and then the Start method to refresh the WaveIn and WaveOut devices to use the current device numbers so users do not see a device selected when a different device is being used. When this happens, the program, rather than crashing instantly and inconsistently, always hangs and has to be killed from the task manager. I am certain these 2 problems are related to the same root cause, but I have no idea what that root cause may be. Switching to Wasapi, DirectSound, or ASIO won't work because they lack certain functionalities I need, so I would really like to get this working still using Wave streams.

I've tried to find different ways to detect the device changes, assuming it is an issue deep inside NAudio, but I just can't find anything else. For the second problem specifically, I have moved the calls to the Mic Injector around thinking it may be a threading issue or something, but it didn't work or change the behavior.

Comment: I seem to remember encountering a deadlock when previously working with something similar to this, you need to ensure that you are stopping the streams on a separate thread, try calling `Stop` from a threadpool thread rather than from a UI event callback.

Comment: @Zintom i actually found the issue recently! it seems that the callback is called before the device switch is completely finished, which led to a lock statement inside NAudio freezing forever because it was waiting on something that was waiting on it. to fix it, i just ran the callback code asynchronously